# Can't Update Store

Tags: c#, ext.net

I'm new to using Ext and could use some help getting an application working. I'm making an application that dynamically creates a Model and Store based on the data coming in from a database. I've got that working, but now I'm trying to implement a search feature, which requires me to refresh the Store each time a user initiates a search.

When loading the GridPanels and Stores, I'm creating the ID's using

```
store.ID = "store-" + categoryID;
```

To reload the stores, I've tried using a Direct Method with the below code:

```
Store store = Ext.Net.X.GetCmp<Ext.Net.Store>("store-" + categoryID);
store.Reload();
```

The reload executes without any errors, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. When I walk through the code, 'store' doesn't appear to bring back any data. I also tried creating a button in the markup with the below:

```
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" Icon="Lightning">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Click Handler="#{store-category}.store.reload();" />
                    </Listeners>
               </ext:Button>
```

The above code returns "Cannot ready property 'reload' of undefined". Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Isn't this the way you're supposed to reload your store?

Thanks

Comment: Err..shouldn't it be `.Reload()` instead of `.reload()`?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I made the change, but I'm still seeing "Cannot read property 'Reload' of undefined"

Comment: In that case I suspect that it cannot find the Store object with `#{store-category}.store`

Comment: where do u bind the store

Comment: @GrawCube It's very strange though. When I go to view-source in by browser, I can see that the ID of the store is set to MainContent_store_category, and the function is calling App.MainContent_store_category.store.Reload();. So it should be finding it.

Comment: @sakir The bind is happening in the C# code on the page load. The way I'm binding is using `code`store.DataSource = DataTable; store.DataBind();`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a button in C# using this:

```
this.SearchForm.Add(new Ext.Net.Button()
            {
                Text = "Search",
                Handler = "ReloadGrid();"
            });
```

ReloadGrid is a JavaScript function which fires this:

```
function ReloadGrid() {
            var obj = Ext.select("#GridID", true).elements;
            Ext.getCmp(obj[0].id).getStore().reload({});
        }
```

This forced the code to reload, and from there I used X.isAjaxRequest to define what area's I want to include only when reloading the page.